# Как избавиться от дублирования SELECT-запроса при вставке в таблицу БД PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

При вставке в таблицу нужно указать id группы, полученного из другой таблицы.
Ставку нужно делать только для одной группы пользователей. Записей может быть очень много - миллионы :)
Вариант "Посмотреть в БД и жестко указать в запросе" не подходит - на разных стендах могут быть разные id.

**Запрос вида:**

```
INSERT INTO accounts(user_id, group_id) VALUES 
('12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789001', (select g.id from groups g where g.name = 'pilots')),
('12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789002', (select g.id from groups g where g.name = 'pilots')),
('12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789003', (select g.id from groups g where g.name = 'pilots')),
('12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789004', (select g.id from groups g where g.name = 'pilots'));
```

надо модифицировать так, чтобы не нужно было N раз делать SELECT, а только один раз в самом начале.

**В MySQL это выглядело бы так:**

```
SELECT id INTO @groupid FROM groups WHERE name = 'pilots';
INSERT INTO accounts(usere_id, group_id) VALUES
    ('12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789001', @groupid),
    ('12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789002', @groupid), 
    ('12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789003', @groupid);
```

С PostgeSQL не получается реализовать.

Comment: Так в постгри так же будет. Создайте переменную, далее в нее селектите и подставляйте в инсерт

Comment: можно использовать подзапрос WITH и попробовать реализацию через него

Comment: *можно использовать подзапрос WITH* Не "можно", а нужно. CTE для того и придуманы, чтобы повторно использовать результаты промежуточной выборки. А ещё разумнее для автора вопроса - почитать наконец букварь по SQL и открыть для себя INSERT .. SELECT. *В MySQL это выглядело бы так* .. и называлось подобное бы так: "сделать через одно место".

Comment: Пока не могу справится с синтаксисом, если кто гуру - подскажите, как правильно написать!

Comment: Забудьте про INSERT .. VALUES. Всё, его не существует. Теперь изучите с нуля INSERT .. SELECT. После изучения задача станет элементарной.

Comment: PS. В MySQL это выглядело бы так: ```INSERT INTO accounts (usere_id, group_id) SELECT '12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789002', id FROM groups WHERE name = 'pilots';```

Comment: Не верный у вас запрос для MySQL. В таблице с группами нет id пользователей. Только названия групп и id групп. Нужно по названию узнать id и использовать его при вставке в таблицу с пользователями.

Comment: Вот потому я и сказал - "изучите с нуля INSERT .. SELECT". Чтобы не говорить откровенную ахинею.

Comment: От ваших комментариев никакого толку, любой может написать "Учи матчасть". Если вы работаете в роли DBA, это не значит, что все тут такие. Вроде как этот ресурс предназначен для вопросов и ответов, а не оскорблений, что все тупые, кроме вас.
Запрос, который вы предлагаете, не корректный, возможно, не внимательно прочитали вопрос...

Comment: "В таблице с группами нет id пользователей" - так и не утверждается, что id пользователей там есть. Запрос типа "SELECT 'здесь никого нет' as message FROM groups WHERE name = 'pilots';" вполне сработает и выдаст это замечательное сообщение столько раз, сколько записей  с name = 'pilots'  в таблице groups, например, 1 раз.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO accounts(user_id, group_id)
select x.user_id, g.id
  from groups g
 cross join (values
     ('12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789001'),
     ('12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789002'),
     ...
 ) as x(user_id)
 where g.name = 'pilots'
```

Answer (score 0):

Предложу еще один ответ, чуть-чуть отличающийся от варианта, предложенного @Mike

```
INSERT INTO accounts(user_id, group_id) 
select user_id,(select g.id from groups g where g.name = 'pilots') group_id 
from (VALUES 
('12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789001'),
('12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789002'),
('12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789003'),
('12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789004')
)t(user_id);
```

Однако, есть сомнения в пояснении к задаче. Представляется, что прямая вставка с большой группы записей с использованием VALUES(x1),...(xn) вряд ли применяется на практике. Скорее всего, это будет выборка из другой таблицы и затем вставка в целевую. Примерно так:

```
INSERT INTO accounts(user_id, group_id) 
select user_id,(select g.id from groups g where g.name = 'pilots') group_id 
from RawData r
where r.groupName='pilots'
```

Т.е. применится операция INSERT INTO ... FROM